# How can i create a fixed footer with a repeated image

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a fixed footer which is a image which is repeated but so far i'm stumped. I tried **Sticky Footer** it repeated and became a footer but it didnt fit to the screen. Right now i have a really simple css and html script.I've also tried Background Repeat X in CSS but it didnt go to the footer.

**CSS**

```
#foot {
height: 187px;
bottom:0;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="foot"><img src="footer.png">
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you want to repeat the image as a background image, then set it as background-image! And please create a jsFiddle or CodePen demo to understand your problem. Or just show us your footer.png image.

Answer (score 2):

dTDesign is right you should use a background image. Example below:

### HTML:

```
<div id="foot"></div>
```

### CSS:

```
#foot {
    height: 187px;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://www.cindyandcarl.com/wp-content/uploads/FooterRepeat.png') repeat-x;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/34DfD/)

Comment: Thanks im not too good at CSS. I tried that but i did background-image which seemed to stuff it up but now its all good. Thank you guys!